# Unable to get the desired look

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucm3i.png)
I am trying to align all the menus including menu, awards, which are present in right side of the header to horizontally.Please provide some code that will help me to provide menu horizontally instead of vertically.I've provided my code snippet that I have used for designing the website using bootstrap, js.

```
            <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li>
                <a href="menu-categories.html" class="pull-left">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span><br 
              class="hidden-xs">Menu</a>
              </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span><br 
              class="hidden-xs">About
                </a>

              </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span><br 
                 class="hidden-xs">Awards</a>
            </li>
            <li id="phone class="hidden-xs">
              <a  href="TEl:8461044634"><span>8461044634</span>
                </a><div>*We  Deliver</div></li>
              </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What ahve you tried already yourself to achieve this? Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you have a *specific* coding question, include a summary of what you have tried and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have styled the list with Bootstrap and you are trying to override it use !important. This isnt best practice though. Better to remove the bootstrap and try solve it with raw css.

```
li { 
 display: inline-block !important; 
}
```

Good luck with the project.

Comment: thanks @Daniel, bro! after removing that bootstrap.min.css that works greatly!

Answer (score 0):

Override the "display" style of the li items like this in CSS:

```
li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```